# How to align text of TextFormField to center, vertical in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to Flutter Development & tried certain work around but nothing really helped. I want my text to be **center vertically** in `TextFormField` in flutter.

`textAlign: TextAlign.start` brings my text to left but I want them to be center vertically also.
`textAlign: TextAlign.center` brings my text to center but I want them to be start from left also.

This is what I am getting,
[image]

This is what I want,
[image]

Snippet of my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Theme(
      data: new ThemeData(
          primaryColor: const Color(0xFF102739),
          accentColor: const Color(0xFF102739),
          hintColor: const Color(0xFF102739)),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            maxLines: 1,
            autofocus: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: const Color(0xFF0f2638),
                fontFamily: 'ProximaNova',
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontSize: 16.0),
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                hintText: "YOUR E-MAIL",
                hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                    color: const Color(0x703D444E),
                    fontFamily: 'ProximaNova',
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    fontSize: 16.0),
                border: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                        color: const Color(0xFF0f2638), width: 0.2))),
            validator: _validateEmail,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )));
}
```

Comment: You mean in TextInput the text should be vertically center?

Comment: Yes right, both hint & input text should be center_vertically @dhuma1981

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Have not received any solution yet, Please answer if You can solve it.

Comment: textAlign: TextAlign.center, is working fine for me

Comment: Just wrap `TextFormField` with Padding and give EdgeInsets.all(/*value*/) as padding.. better to contain all in a container. and give shapeDecoration to container and inside that TextFormField with Padding. and remove all textAlign property

Answer (score 25):

There is no vertical align option for that. All you need to do is to set `contentPadding` for positioning:

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero
     )
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syZba.png)

Comment: Sadly I couldn't figure out how to right align the label text, but this solution gave me an idea to do it.

Answer (score 19):

Use the following property:

```
TextFormField(
textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
//Remaining code.
),
```

Answer (score 10):

So it worked perfectly for me:

```
TextFormField(
  // setting text alignment
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    // decorating and styling your Text
    isCollapsed: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 8):

The way I did it using "**alignment: Alignment.center,**" for Container with "**InputDecoration.collapsed**" & "**.copyWith(isDense: true)**":

```
          Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.red,
                      decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintText: 'Search',
                      ).copyWith(isDense: true),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: isCollapsed is the right anwer, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
TextFormField(
 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

You can use decoration attribute like this:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isCollapsed: true,
                        isDense: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
    ),
```